# Can't see, change, add or remove plugin or theme in a previously multisite WordPress installation. What should I do?

Tags: wordpress

hope you're having a great weekend. I need some help, please!

There's this client's website which was in a multisite network in another company, and **I was hired to migrate it to a Cloudways server.**

The previous company sent me a backup with all the folders and files and the database. **I managed to upload the files to the new server, import the database and connect everything.**

So, the site is online on the new Cloudways server, **but as you can *(or can't)* see, there's no "Plugins" menu in the backend.**

Through the FTP **I got to the wp-content/plugins folder, but there's no user role plugin there to deactivate**. **The user has the Administrator role** and now I really don't know what to do.

Any help, please?

--

EDIT: Nor can I change themes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dleX.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the account you're using to log in doesn't have enough permissions to see these menu items? Have you tried creating another WP account with admin privileges yet? (Check on Google for tutorials on creating admin accounts via phpmyadmin in case you haven't tried it yet/don't know how-to.)

Answer (score 0):

Only "super admin", can install plugins
[image]

I think you need to ask for Supper Admin account login.

## UPDATE

I just found some other easy solutions for you [here:](https://drawne.com/add-super-admin-wordpress-network/)